# Arranging python array

Tags: python, arrays

When I run the following code:

```
array1 = ["happy", "sad","good", "bad","like"]
array2=["i like starhub", "i am happy with the starhub service", "starhub is      bad"," this is not awful"]

for i in array1:
    for j in array2:
        if i in j :
            print i
```

The result printed will be

```
happy
bad
like
```

The output is printed according to the order they're listed in `array1`. How can I sort the output according to `array2`? I would like the output to be:

```
like
happy
bad
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leb's answer is right on the money; please upvote and accept it.

I just want to add a note about naming conventions.

In many programming languages, variable names `i` and `j` are traditionally used for numeric loop indexes, but not for the actual values of the elements in a list or array.

For example (pun intended), if you were writing an old-fashioned `for` loop in JavaScript, it might look like this:

```
var names = [ "Kent", "Leb", "Dalen" ];
for( var i = 0;  i < names.length;  i++ ) {
    console.log( names[i] );
}
```

You could also write code like this in Python, but since you're using the more expressive Python `for` loop, you can use better names than `i` and `j`.

As Dalen notes in a comment, the names `array1` and `array2` don't match Python terminology—but more importantly, they don't say anything about what is *in* these lists.

It is helpful to use more self-explanatory variable names throughout. In your code, the two lists are a list of words and a list of phrases, and the variables in the loops represent a single word and a single phrase.

A convention I like here is to use a plural name for a list or array, and the corresponding singular name for an individual element of that list or array.

So you could use names like this:

```
words = [ "happy", "sad", "good", "bad", "like" ]
phrases = [
    "i like starhub",
    "i am happy with the starhub service",
    "starhub is bad",
    " this is not awful"
]

for phrase in phrases:
    for word in words:
        if word in phrase:
            print( word )
```

Do you see how much more clear this makes the code? Instead of `i` and `j` and `array1` and `array2` (or `list1` and `list2`), each name describes the actual data you're working with.

Answer (score 3):

Switch the loop:

```
list1 = ["happy", "sad", "good", "bad", "like"]
list2 = ["i like starhub", "i am happy with the starhub service", "starhub is bad", " this is not awful"]

for j in list2:
    for i in list1:
        if i in j:
            print(i)


>>like
>>happy
>>bad
```

The one on top is what's being used as the primary list. So in your case, `list1` was the primary and being sorted as such.

In the one I gave, `list2` is the primary instead.

Comment: That what you are using here aren't arrays. These are lists. Array in Python would be: "import array; a1 = array.array([1, 2, 3])". Please edit your post so that it won't confuse others.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for bringing this up to my attention.

Comment: Woops, its: array.array("h", [1, 2, 3]). Sorry, forgot that you have to specify the type.